# CD Creator/Burner has frozen

Tags: cd

I was burning something on to a blank CD. Now at the top it says "100% Done", but well I don't know? It shows the downloading status at like 1/4, but it's been like this for hours. Under that it says "Creating Image Checksum".

Any ideas what's up?

Comment: use a usb instead of a CD?

Comment: "Downloading status"?  What?  Are you downloading something else while burning a cd?  This doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try quitting from (or killing) the CD Creator software, then ejecting and reinserting the burnt CD and see if the data is on it or not.

I am having problems with k3b (a different burning program) at the moment where it tells me the burn has failed, but when I check the logs I see it failed after the process was 100% complete, and when I check what is on the CD it is all there.